# Change the default double-click action for a Directory

Tags: file, key, registry, explorer, regedit

So I have been trying to add a program I wrote to the registry so that it will show up in the Context Menu. I went into regedit and added the key under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Directory\shell. The other two things there are cmd and find. I right-clicked shell and added a key but for some reason, its setting that to the default. Obviously I don't want my program to run on every single directory. Is there a way I can change the default action back to file explorer while still adding my program to the context menu? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer on this site. 
https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/19449-default-file-type-associations-restore.html
It turns out an installer I wrote had messed with my registry in a weird way. I was able to find the default registry in that site and restored it. I would highly recommend backing up your registry before attempting to make changes.